# Trouble with do while and prompt with javascript

Tags: javascript, command-prompt, do-while

I have a problem to display the contents of a data block with the do while loop which also displays the function prompt () to send the choice in the block wish the console hangs

```
var choix;
listeChoix();
do{
    choix = prompt("Choisir une option ");
    listeChoix();
    var ChoixNumber = parseInt(choix) ;
    if(ChoixNumber==1){
        //console.log("Welcome in choice 1")
         //affiche();
        console.log("la taille ", choix.length);      

    }
    if(ChoixNumber==2){
        console.log("Dans 2");

    }    
}while (ChoixNumber!=0)

function affiche(){
    console.log("Hello");

}
function listeChoix(){
    console.log("1 : Lister les contacts");    
    console.log("2 : Ajouter un contact");
    console.log("0 : Quitter");
}

console.log("Au revoir !");
```

And if I want to display another console or function in choice == 1 the browser crashes with the presence of prompt block and nothing in the console appears. I do not know why?

Help me and thank you in advance

Comment: your code is working OK, just tested it in Firefox console.

Comment: may I suggest CTRL+ SHIFT + DEL ?

Comment: Thanks my friend it's resolved with firefox :)